# Java Based lightweight Table alternatives

Tags: java, swing

We are using Table Library for our application. If we load 10000x100 records in the table it consumes 3/4 of the application memory and the application hangs.

Can anyone suggest a lightweight Java Swing Table that consumes less memory and has features such as filtering, sorting, etc.

Comment: Ya while loading the data in table model, it consumes memory. is there any difference between table and table model?, model help to add data in table?

Comment: @Joey: bzzzt, wrong, bogus, uninformed.  JTable perfs are actually **pathetic** when it comes to manipulating a huge amount of data.  You **do** want to read the following Sun doc: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/ChristmasTree/  There are a **lot** of reason that makes JTable behave abysmally poorly in a lot of case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lightweight Java table is JTable. You can do almost whatever you like, if you use extend AbstractTableModel and use a sorter and a Renderer. Since the model provides the view with data you will never need to exhaust your memory with loading all your information.

When you say, 10000x100 if 100 is the number of columns it is probably a bit too much for the average monitor. You probably have to make a discount there or make it scroll horizontally.

If you let the model get the data from the database, you will never need to load your entire table, so there should probably be no problem with a JTable width of 50-100 or even more.

Be careful: In order to make your JTable called "jTable1" scroll horizontally well, set

```
jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

The JTable Class has a sorter and filtering.

Read the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more.

Comment: i just gave example, actually we are having maximum of 50-60 columns.

Comment: can u suggest some third part tableslib which has sorting,filtering and pagination.

Comment: JXTable is a nice extension that might be useful to you. http://xframe.sourceforge.net/swing/index.html

Comment: @CostisAivalis: I'm sorry but a JTable is **NOT** light at all.  It is about as bloated as one can get.  You probably do want to google on the Sun *"Christmas Tree"* demo application which very nicely explains why default JTable are simply not cutting it when you need to manipulate a lot of data (like, for instance, constantly updating financial data).  I can't believe you got 3 clueless upvotes for this karma-whoring answer.

Comment: Nobody is talking about Xmas trees here nor about constantly updating anything. Read the question: he wanted to show 10000x100 records. http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/swing2.html ---Lightweight Components---

All components in Project Swing, except JApplet, JDialog, JFrame and JWindow are lightweight components. Lightweight components, unlike their Abstract Window Toolkit (AWT) counterparts, do not depend on the local windowing toolkit.

Comment: even more sadening is the fact that this non-answer got 3 upvotes while the question didn't get upvoted (besides my +1).

Comment: Thanks for reply, we are mostly using scientific grid in our application. It hangs when load the data in table model. we have load such amount of data for some important business review purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Table or no Table. loading 10000X100 records into memory sounds like bad design, especially if you are limited in memory.

try using Flyweight design pattern if it suits your application and if not try loading only relevant parts of the table each time.

Comment: i just gave an example over there. we won't load that much columns. Do you know any third party tablelib, which consumes less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Most proabably the problem is related to your domain model.. 10000 object is not too much, even if your domain object has 100 fields..But if your object graph is too deep and complex, number of objects increases to billions instead of millions.. Therefore , I recommend strongly you to review your domain model..

Comment: row will be likes 10000 but columns will be around 50-60 columns. can you suggest any third part tablelib which consumes less memory and light weight.

Comment: I do not suggest any other table component consumes less memory.. The flaw is related to domain model, not table component.

Comment: It seems that the down-voter is preparing for Christmas although it almost easter time. Anyway i will up-vote your answer because i think it is correct.

Comment: @Costis Aivalis thanks for your explanation. I believe that downvoter should explain their reasoning, by this way I can learn what is wrong with my answer..

Comment: Do you know any thing about scientific grid